# Could anyone explain me why my question was deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions, specific-question

I asked a question on askubuntu.com. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111486/upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04-broke-apt)
First it was put on hold, because it was too broad. So I edited my question to make it more specific.
Some hours later the question was deleted without any comment.

- I researched half a day before asking the question.
- The English was not the best, but it was ok.
- As far as I perceived it the question was detailed and very specific.

So I can't think of any reason why my question was deleted.
I'd be glad if anyone could help me solving this mystery.

Comment: I voted to delete after it was closed and still looked 'too-broad' (i.e. before you made the edit). It looks fine to me now, I voted to 'undelete'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This appears to have gone full circuit already. I think you're in a good place now but here's the abridged timeline:

- Five people voted to close it for being "too broad"
- You edited it and a review was started to reopen.
- Before that completed three users voted to delete it.
- You posted this.
- Three users (including one of the ones who voted to delete it) voted to undelete it.
- Other stuff happened.
- Here we are.

Essentially it was deleted because the delete voters happened before the reopen review happened.

From a technical aspect, it's not entirely simple *what should* happen here. Delete voters are usually of a higher reputation so if they think it should be deleted, even after editing, perhaps their votes should stand... But similarly —and it's a point I've made a few dozen times— **they're doing nobody any favours by voting to delete** soft issue things in the first place.

I can't tell you why people did the things they did, only offer my exasperation that this stuff still happens every so often. Thankfully nothing is permanent so I trust everything is well now. Good luck with the problem and welcome to the site.

Comment: Could you please expand upon "*they're doing nobody any favours by voting to delete soft issue*..."? A good number of questions (mostly by new users) get closed every single day as unclear / off-topic / opinion based / too broad etc. and almost always they're abandoned. Manually deleting such questions to clean up the site is not necessarily a useless thing imo as automatic removal take some time. Moreover, if I'm not mistaken, a question with positive score is *not* auto-removed. And as I observed, sympathy/pity upvotes on questions happen a lot here at AU.

Comment: There is even a user who had the nickname "user who upvotes all downvoted posts" (or something close)! :-\

Comment: @pomsky Phrases like "clean up" highlight the problem. It's a website, not a bedroom. Our raison d'être is helping people, getting them an answer. Closed questions don't stop that in any way. **The delete queue is busywork**, carried out by experienced users who think they're doing something important *because* it's a feature that's retained for high reputation users. The absolute best thing those users could do is triage and answer the [new questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=newest). It's a travesty that the gamification of administrative tasks ends up undermining the site.

Comment: There's a lot to unpack there. I don't think deleters are malevolent in any way... I just think that as the upper echelon of features open up to users, they get distracted by them. It sustains a lie that moderation is more important than posting an answer because a 1-rep user can do that. There *are* important review tasks (edits, first posts, things that make our other users better) but delete isn't one of them.